# Configuring IIS as reverse-proxy for Keycloak

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, keycloak, arr

I'm using Keycloak 2.3.0 version, standalone mode, server. I configured IIS URL Rewrite for local Keycloak server running on localhost:8080.

The problem is that there is no way to specify base url in Keycloak, instead Keycloak tries to detect its own host/port and always appends port number (8080) to redirects.
I fixed everything except 'auth-server-url' in config json. Is there any way to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

I've been running *Keycloak* behind a reverse-proxy for some time. The key is:

- to have it configured properly in `standalone.xml` - *HTTPS proxy* settings for *mydomain.com/**sso*** settings follow:

  - `<http-listener name="default"... -> <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" proxy-address-forwarding="true" redirect-socket="proxy-https"/>`
  - `<socket-binding name="http"... -> <socket-binding name="proxy-https" port="443"/>`
  - `<web-context>auth... -> <web-context>sso</web-context>`
- to run it on the same *context path* as the proxy is. Eg. `mydomain.com/keycloak -> localhost:8080/keycloak`
- to access *Keycloak admin console* **from the non-local address** for **the first time** - it generates some of its settings based on this first access

Comment: Could you point directly to reverse-proxy related configuration? I even looked through the source code and it seems that keycloak uses request path to generate redirects (for saml), which is localhost:8080 and it is wrong... Which operating mode do you use?

Comment: I have no experience with _SAML_ based auth in Keycloak... Anyway, I've added example of changes needed to be done in `standalone.xml` for a HTTPS proxying. I can also stress out the need of **accessing the admin console from the proxy** and not the local address for the first time.

Comment: @kemsky https://www.keycloak.org/docs/7.0/server_installation/#enable-https-ssl-with-a-reverse-proxy
I know this answer is old but I was struggling to find the link and this SO question was in the top google search.