# Configure reverse-proxy for Keycloak docker with custom base URL

Tags: nginx, docker, keycloak

How can I set the `docker keycloak base url` as parameter ?

I have the following nginx reverse proxy configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /keycloak {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8087/;
    }
}
```

When I try to access http://example.com/keycloak/ I got a keycloak http redirect to http://example.com/auth/ instead of http://example.com/keycloak/auth/

Any ideas?

Comment: FrancoisMaturel suggestion: `location /keycloak { proxy_pass http://example.com:8087/keycloak;}` @FrançoisMaturel I tried what you suggested but it did not work

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just tested that @home, and actually multiple configuration additions are needed:

1/ Run the keycloak container with env **[`-e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/)** as explained in the docs, this is required in a proxy way of accessing to keycloak:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8087:8080 --name keycloak -e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true jboss/keycloak:latest
```

Also explained in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388028/configuring-iis-as-reverse-proxy-for-keycloak)

2/ Change the **web-context** inside keycloak's configuration file `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`

Default keycloak configuration points to `auth`

```
<web-context>auth</web-context>
```

Then you could change it to `keycloak/auth`

```
<web-context>keycloak/auth</web-context>
```

If you need to automate this for docker, just create a new keycloak image :

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest

USER jboss

RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
```

3/ Add some proxy information to nginx configuration (mostly for http / https handling)

```
location /keycloak {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8087;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

If you are proxying requests from nginx to keycloak on same server, I recommend using `proxy_pass http://localhost:8087;`, and if not try to use a private network to avoid proxying through external web requests.

Hope this helps

Comment: Are these dependent steps? Or there 3 ways to tackle this issue?

Comment: @nurgasemetey, all thoses steps are needed to resolve this issue

Comment: It seems like this approach leads to subtile semantic errors - see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-11529 for an example that is currently hitting me ...

Comment: @col.panic this seems to be related to latest version of keycloak, please update me if you find a working solution

Comment: @FrançoisMaturel please see the resp. jboss ticket - i find a workaround/solution

Comment: Just an upgrade - My nginx is hidden behind Apache and all internal requests are forwarded over http, so header `X-Forwarded-Proto $remote_addr` did not work for me. I had to set `X-forwarded-Proto https`. Otherwise browser was yelling at me some errors with https -> http insecure requests,

Comment: I am using keycloak behind a nginx proxy and had the same issue. For me it was enough to just give keycloak the env variable PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true. The other configuration might not be necessary in every case.

Comment: That's not really good... what if in production they can set up any context path they want? This is a build-time solution but I need a runtime approach. We manage the context-path totally with ingress which is the infrastructure's team responsibility and during the development we don't know what context-path they want to choose. Is it possible to replace the `web-context` with an environment variable?

Comment: @MarcB. I am using keycloak behind a nginx proxy and for me it was necessary to add the configuration under 3/. I wonder what's the difference. Are you running within a docker(-compose) environment?

Comment: @MarkusRohlof I just checked again and we are not using any of the configurations under 3/. And yes, we run it in within a docker-compose env.

Answer (score 18):

The redirect from `/keycloak` to `/keycloak/auth` isn't working.
The redirect route in `index.html` and `Base-URL` is missing the `/keycloak` part.
I had to add this:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest

USER jboss

RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/name="\/"/name="\/keycloak\/"/' $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/name="\/"/name="\/keycloak\/"/' $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/\/auth/\/keycloak\/auth/' $JBOSS_HOME/welcome-content/index.html
RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' $JBOSS_HOME/domain/configuration/domain.xml
```

Comment: This sadly did not help for me on Keycloak v11.0.2 - there are possibly even more instances which need to be replaced meanwhile?

Comment: @pat-s there are some new files:

`RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' $JBOSS_HOME/domain/configuration/domain.xml`

Comment: Tested, adding it to answer...

Answer (score 10):

Building on @Francois Maturel's response: for the latest Keycloak (currently 4.8.x), I had to add an additional line to replace the `web-context` in `standalone-ha.xml` as well:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest
USER jboss
RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/\/auth/\/keycloak\/auth/' /opt/jboss/keycloak/welcome-content/index.html
```

The reason is that the `docker-entrypoint.sh` startup script will use `standalone-ha.xml` configuration in addition to `standalone.xml` unless the `-c` flag is passed.  See here: https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/server/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh

Comment: Worked, but e.g. `localhost:8080/` was still directed to  `localhost:8080/auth` instead of  `localhost:8080/keycloak/auth` , added a line for index.html to fix... But maybe 
@Andreas_Burghardt  answer is more  complete...

Answer (score 10):

In Keycloak 18.x you can't use `web-context` anymore.

There is now a new argument `http-relative-path`, which contains the path relative to '/'.

CLI: `--http-relative-path`

Env: `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH`

Comment: this should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 2):

i can also confirm that when using docker image keycloak 6.0.1 standalone-ha.xml file also needs to be changed using the sed command...

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have an existing Keycloak (v8.0.1) on Docker, so I had to update the database as well.

1. Launch Keycloak Docker container with the following environment variable:

   PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
2. Update the database. I'm using Postgres.

   psql -U keycloak -d keycloak

   update realm set ssl_required='NONE';
3. Restart Keycloak

[Example for Postgres DB, by Sairam Krish](https://medium.com/@sairamkrish/keycloak-integration-part-1-overview-812010d6c7cf)