# Keycloak path settings

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse, keycloak

I am trying to run Keycloak 3.2.1.Final behind a nginx reverse Proxy (later this will become Ingress). The goal is to reach the same keycloak service from different adresses like so:

- a.com/foo1/baz1/keycloak/(auth/realms/...)
- a.com/foo2/baz2/keycloak/(auth/realms/...)
- ...

and so on.

What I managed to do was change the `standalone.xml` *`<web-context>`* setting from '*auth*' to '*foo1/baz1/keycloak*' and reach the service like this:

- localhost:8081/foo1/bar1/keycloak/

but in no combination of configs was I able to make the Nginx Proxy and the Keycloak server work together to be reached via the a.com domain on Port 80.

There is a solution to a very similar question @ [Configure reverse-proxy for Keycloak docker with custom base URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624844/configure-reverse-proxy-for-keycloak-docker-with-custom-base-url)

but this does not seem to work (anymore?).

Ty for your time.

Answer (score 8):

In **Keycloak 18.x** you can set `http-relative-path` argument, which contains the path relative to '/'.

CLI: `--http-relative-path`

Env: `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH`

Comment: This is the best and easiest solution to the problem and the only one that worked for me. It is much simpler than modifying xml files nested deep inside keycloak. I know "thank you" messages are frowned on here but honestly, thank you so much

Comment: @AnishSinha I spent a lot of time modifying xmls until I found it, I am glad it helped you too :)

Comment: could kiss you. It took like an hour till I found this post. Seems like absolutely one of the most common configurations that would be wanted and Im surprised it was not better documented. I was chasing after hostname-path which apparently does not work even though their documentation literally says "set this if behind proxy and you want a different path" ....

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54311713/2117355

In recent versions of Keycloak, you also need to modify `standalone-ha.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Usecase: Behind proxy
If ur using jboss/keycloak you can update context path like this:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak

RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
RUN sed -i -e 's/\/auth/\/keycloak\/auth/' /opt/jboss/keycloak/welcome-content/index.html
```

Or do to same change (Update web-context) standalon config: `<KEYCLOAK_HOME>/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`