# Keycloak on Azure App Service for Containers fails with "Uncaught ReferenceError: Keycloak is not defined" error

Tags: docker, keycloak, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy Keycloak from public docker hub to Azure App Service for Containers.
It works fine, but when I try to access administration console I'm getting following response:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Keycloak is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:12)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

When I trying same locally, all works fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING to true and it did the work.

Found an answer here:

[Configure reverse-proxy for Keycloak docker with custom base URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624844/configure-reverse-proxy-for-keycloak-docker-with-custom-base-url)

Comment: this also worked for my docker container on plesk, thanks!